# Java - IntelliJ not finding module-libraries stated in module-info.java when the application is ran

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

**MY SETUP:**

I followed the steps for the **JavaFX and IntelliJ** -> **Modular from IDE** [path](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

I added the **ikonli-core-12.2.0.jar**, **ikonli-javafx-12.2.0.jar** and **ikonli-carbonicons-pack-12.2.0.jar** via the repository to the Scene Builder in this order. Here, they work fine.

Then I added those same `.jars` in that same order to the IntelliJ as described here: [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project).

My **module-info.java** file contains the following code:

```
module project {

    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.core;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.carbonicons;

    opens com.project to javafx.fxml;

    exports com.project;
}
```

Picture of my libraries:

[image: Libraries]

**PROBLEM:**

When I add an icon to the `.fxml` file and I click on **Run**, I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx not found, required by project
```

The module name varies. Sometimes it says it's the `javafx`, others the `core` or the `carbonicons`.

<strike>I'm not sure why this happens. When I'm typing in the **module-info.java** file I get the autofill prompts, , but when I try, for example, `import org.kordamp.ikonli.core;` in my `Main.java`, **it doesn't** detect them.</strike>

I'm not sure why this happens. When I'm typing in the **module-info.java** file or try `import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon;` in my `Main.java`, I get the autofill prompts, so it means it's detecting them.

If I remove the "ikonli requires" from the **module-info.java** and run it, I get this error (which is kind of understandable):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon`

**SOLUTIONS I'VE TRIED:**

1. Adding the `.jars` via **File** -> **Project Settings** -> **Libraries**.

This seems to automatically add them to the **Modules** -> **Dependencies**, but even so, the problem persists.

2. Adding them in the **VM Options** (**Run** -> **Edit Configuration** -> **Modify Options** -> **VM Options**) in various ways, right after the `--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX}:out/production` mentioned in the steps linked above (`out` can be safely changed to `mods` but I chose not to do that).

**First:**

`--module-path ${PATH_TO_IKONLI_CORE}`, `--module-path ${PATH_TO_IKONLI_JAVAFX}` and `--module-path ${PATH_TO_IKONLI_CARBONICONS}`

Doing this makes it so my actual `project` module doesn't get detected. I.E. I get this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module project not found
```

**Second:**

`--add-modules ${PATH_TO_IKONLI_CORE},${PATH_TO_IKONLI_JAVAFX},${PATH_TO_IKONLI_CARBONICONS}`

This one produces a smiliar error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module /directory/path/to/file/ikonli-core-12.2.0.jar not found
```

**Third:**

`--add-modules org.kordamp.ikonli.core,org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx,org.kordamp.ikonli.carbonicons`

A similar error shows up:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.kordamp.ikonli.core not found
```

3. I tried **File** -> **Reload all from disk** and **Invalidate Caches / Restart** options, but they seem to have had no effect.
4. I created a `lib` folder in my `src` project folder, put the `.jars` there and added them as dependencies. Now they didn't show up in the `External Libraries` section (because they're not external obviously) but the problem remains (I'll re-add them as external again).

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

I've added `controlsfx.jar` the same way as the Ikonli `.jars`. The same error occurs for it as well.

They all have their **module-info.class** file in the proper directory as stated in the [official javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html), yet the `ModuleFinder` still throws the exception.

I've also checked my `project.iml` file and they all have the `module-libraries` with the correct directories present.

I've revisted the [official Ikonli installation steps](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/) multiple times and everything checks out.

Though, in there it mentions that I need to have `requires javafx.base; requires javafx.graphics;` in the module descriptor. Not true, at least in my case, because when I add `--show-module-resolution` to the **VM Options**, it shows that they're loaded fine, but even when I do add them, the error still appears.

**END**

Sorry for the long post, I'm out of ideas and I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148046/javafx-jlink-jpackage-module-issue-adding-libraries-error-occurred-during-in?rq=1) mentioned that they'd put their `.jar` in the `mods/production` folder. I did the same... and it worked. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

[image: bruh]

I guess "Modular from IDE" doesn't agree with the IDE.

Looks like the **proper** way to go about modular is to use Maven/Gradle. I'll rebuild and go with Gradle.